# CreateFile fails on opening fs driver

Tags: c#, driver, createfile

i'm trying to communicate with my filesystem driver. I can start the driver with OpenSCManager, CreateService and OpenService but when i'm trying to use "CreateFile", it always says Errorcode 2 (I think it's file not found etc.).

This is the whole code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Management;
using System.ServiceProcess;


namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public sealed class Win32Driver : IDisposable
    {


        string driverName;
        string execPath;
        IntPtr fileHandle;
        public Win32Driver(string driver, string driverExecPath)
        {
            this.driverName = driver;
            this.execPath = driverExecPath;
        }
        ~Win32Driver()
        {
            // BUG - should never rely on finalizer to clean-up unmanaged resources
            Dispose();
        }
        private void CloseStuff()
        {
            if (fileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                fileHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
                CloseHandle(fileHandle);
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            CloseStuff();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }






        private readonly static IntPtr INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = new IntPtr(-1);
        private const int STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000F0000;
        private const int SC_MANAGER_CONNECT = 0x0001;
        private const int SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE = 0x0002;
        private const int SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE = 0x0004;
        private const int SC_MANAGER_LOCK = 0x0008;
        private const int SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS = 0x0010;
        private const int SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG = 0x0020;
        private const int SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED |
        SC_MANAGER_CONNECT |
        SC_MANAGER_CREATE_SERVICE |
        SC_MANAGER_ENUMERATE_SERVICE |
        SC_MANAGER_LOCK |
        SC_MANAGER_QUERY_LOCK_STATUS |
        SC_MANAGER_MODIFY_BOOT_CONFIG;

        private const int SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG = 0x0001;
        private const int SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG = 0x0002;
        private const int SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS = 0x0004;
        private const int SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS = 0x0008;
        private const int SERVICE_START = 0x0010;
        private const int SERVICE_STOP = 0x0020;
        private const int SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE = 0x0040;
        private const int SERVICE_INTERROGATE = 0x0080;
        private const int SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL = 0x0100;

        private const int SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED
        |
        SERVICE_QUERY_CONFIG |
        SERVICE_CHANGE_CONFIG |
        SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS |
        SERVICE_ENUMERATE_DEPENDENTS |
        SERVICE_START |
        SERVICE_STOP |
        SERVICE_PAUSE_CONTINUE |
        SERVICE_INTERROGATE |
        SERVICE_USER_DEFINED_CONTROL;

        private const int SERVICE_DEMAND_START = 0x00000003;
        private const int SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER = 0x00000001;
        private const int SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL = 0x00000001;

        private const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
        private const uint FILE_SHARE_READ = 1;
        private const uint FILE_SHARE_WRITE = 2;
        private const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;
        private const uint IOCTL_SHOCKMGR_READ_ACCELEROMETER_DATA = 0x733fc;
        private const int FACILITY_WIN32 = unchecked((int)0x80070000);
        private IntPtr handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string machineName, string
        databaseName, uint dwDesiredAccess);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CreateService(IntPtr hSCManager, string
        serviceName, string displayName,
        uint dwDesiredAccess, uint serviceType, uint startType, uint
        errorControl,
        string lpBinaryPathName, string lpLoadOrderGroup, string lpdwTagId,
        string lpDependencies,
        string lpServiceStartName, string lpPassword);

        [DllImport("advapi32")]
        internal static extern bool CloseServiceHandle(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, uint dwDesiredAccess);

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint
        dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint
        dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);


        [DllImport("kernel32")]
        internal static extern void CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool DeviceIoControl(IntPtr hDevice, uint
        dwIoControlCode, IntPtr lpInBuffer, uint nInBufferSize, IntPtr lpOutBuffer,
        uint nOutBufferSize, ref uint lpBytesReturned, IntPtr lpOverlapped);


        internal bool LoadDeviceDriver()
        {
        IntPtr scHandle = OpenSCManager(null, null, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

        Console.WriteLine("OpenSCManager: " + scHandle);

        if (scHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
        IntPtr hService = CreateService(scHandle, this.driverName,
                                        this.driverName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS
                                        , SERVICE_KERNEL_DRIVER, SERVICE_DEMAND_START,SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL
                                        ,execPath, null, null, null, null, null);

        Console.WriteLine("CreateService: " + hService);

        hService = OpenService(scHandle, this.driverName,
                       SERVICE_START | SERVICE_STOP);

        Console.WriteLine("OpenService: "+hService);


        if (hService != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
        CloseServiceHandle(hService); // close both handles
        CloseServiceHandle(scHandle);
        // Start the driver using System.Management (WMI)
        if (ExecuteSCMOperationOnDriver(this.driverName, "StartService") == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        }
        else
        if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()== 1073) // Driver/Service already in DB
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Marshal=1073");
        CloseServiceHandle(scHandle);
        // Start the driver using System.Management (WMI)
        if (ExecuteSCMOperationOnDriver(this.driverName, "StartService") == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        }
        Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        }
        return false;
        }

        internal bool UnloadDeviceDriver()
        {
            int ret = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Unloading now...");
            if (fileHandle != IntPtr.Zero && fileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                CloseHandle(fileHandle);
            }
            if ((ret = ExecuteSCMOperationOnDriver(driverName, "StopService")) == 0)
            {
                ret = ExecuteSCMOperationOnDriver(driverName, "Delete");
            }
            if (ret != 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private static int ExecuteSCMOperationOnDriver(string driverName, string operation)
        {
            ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath();
            path.Server = ".";
            path.NamespacePath = @"root\CIMV2";
            path.RelativePath = @"Win32_BaseService.Name='" + driverName + "'";
            using (ManagementObject o = new ManagementObject(path))
            {
                ManagementBaseObject outParams = o.InvokeMethod(operation,null, null);
                return Convert.ToInt32(outParams.Properties["ReturnValue"].Value);
            }
        }

        internal IntPtr OpenDevice()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(driverName);


            fileHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\"+driverName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

            Console.WriteLine("CreateFile: "+fileHandle);
            //Console.WriteLine(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());


        if(fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Throw exception");
            Console.WriteLine((Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).ToString()+"\n\n\n");
            //Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        }
        return fileHandle;
        }


        internal IntPtr DevControl()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DevControl started");
            //long DeviceBuffer = 0;
            IntPtr dwState = new IntPtr(100);
            uint dwRet=0;

            bool dc = DeviceIoControl(fileHandle, FSConstants.IO_SET_EVENT, IntPtr.Zero, 0, dwState, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(dwRet), ref dwRet, IntPtr.Zero);

            Console.WriteLine("Operation: "+dc);
            Console.WriteLine("Return Value: "+dwRet);
            Console.WriteLine("Error: "+(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).ToString() + "\n\n\n");
            if (fileHandle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Throw exception");
                //Console.WriteLine((Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).ToString()+"\n\n\n");
                //Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
            }
            return fileHandle;
        }



        private static int HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(int x)
        {
            return x <= 0 ? x : ((x & 0x0000FFFF) | FACILITY_WIN32);
        }
    }

    internal class FSConstants
    {
        private const int FILE_DEVICE_COMM_DRIVER = 0x00008810;
        const uint METHOD_NEITHER = 3;
        const uint METHOD_BUFFERED = 0;

        const uint FILE_ANY_ACCESS = 0;
        const uint FILE_SPECIAL_ACCESS = FILE_ANY_ACCESS;


        public static uint IO_SET_EVENT = CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_COMM_DRIVER, 0x801, METHOD_NEITHER, FILE_ANY_ACCESS);


        static uint CTL_CODE(uint DeviceType, uint Function, uint Method, uint Access)
        {
            return ((DeviceType) << 16) | ((Access) << 14) | ((Function) << 2) | (Method);
        }
    }


}
```

and my main:

```
[...]
   class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern int ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern int SuspendThread(IntPtr hThread);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr OpenThread(ThreadAccess dwDesiredAccess,
            bool bInheritHandle,
            uint dwThreadId
        );

        [Flags]
        public enum ThreadAccess : int
        {
            TERMINATE = (0x0001),
            SUSPEND_RESUME = (0x0002),
            GET_CONTEXT = (0x0008),
            SET_CONTEXT = (0x0010),
            SET_INFORMATION = (0x0020),
            QUERY_INFORMATION = (0x0040),
            SET_THREAD_TOKEN = (0x0080),
            IMPERSONATE = (0x0100),
            DIRECT_IMPERSONATION = (0x0200)
        }


        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint
        dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint
        dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

        private const uint GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000;
        private const uint OPEN_EXISTING = 3;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool check=true;
            string driverName = "FsFilter";

            //load systemdriver
            Win32Driver driver = new Win32Driver(driverName,@"c:\\FsFilter.sys");
            if (driver.LoadDeviceDriver()){
                Console.WriteLine(driverName + " loaded");
                IntPtr handle = driver.OpenDevice();
                Console.WriteLine(handle);
                Console.WriteLine("Device opened");
                // use device using ....DeviceIoControl(handle,....) see class code for signature
                driver.DevControl();
            }
            //unload when done
            Console.Read();
            driver.DevControl();
            driver.UnloadDeviceDriver();
            Console.WriteLine(driverName + " unloaded");
            Console.Read();
}
[...]
```

Output is:

```
OpenSCManager: 1576104
CreateService: 1576624
OpenService: 1576704
FsFilter loaded
FsFilter
CreateFile: -1
Throw exception
2



-1
Device opened
DevControl started
Operation: False
Return Value: 0
Error: 6

Unloading now...
FsFilter unloaded
```

DriverLoading and Unloading works fine (checked with DebugView). The problem is that CreateFile always says "-1" / "2". I've tested it with other drivers but still the same. When I'm opening a textfile with CreateFile, it works fine, but i want to communicate with my driver (DeviceIOControl), so i need to open the driver-device...

Can someone help me / give me a hint?
Thanks!

Comment: So you are getting IVALID_HANDLE_VALUE from creatfile.  Also is this in windows 7/vista or xp.

Comment: It's build in Windows7 and started in WinXP. Driver is also optimized for WinXP Environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am wondering how the driver failed to load and yet got 'unloaded'...also, I just have to query this....

```
Win32Driver driver = new Win32Driver(driverName,@"c:\\FsFilter.sys");
```

Why is the name of the driver hardcoded, not alone that, you are using the 'verbatim' string so there is no need to escape the back-slash...have you tried it this way:

```
Win32Driver driver = new Win32Driver(driverName, Path.Combine(@"C:\", driverName));
```

Another thing...when a call is made via 'CreateFile', you are passing in an existing filename 'FsFilter.sys' for reading yet, it already was loaded...? Should that have been `\\.\FsFilter` with the extension dropped...these are the things I notice and have a question mark about...?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: When I change the Win32Driver initialization to your suggestion, the program can't find the sys file to load, because it needs the full path of it. I don't think that there is a problem, because the driver loading and unloading works already.
The extension is not needed for CreateFile calling a system driver. Only the driver name I think (but I've also tried to createfile with driverName+".sys" etc. did not work.)
Thank you.

Comment: @t0mm13b, for some strange reason my driver wont at Win2k8 nless its ImagePath was set to \SystemRoot\drivers\????.sys, as error 7000 (file not found) was popping into logs unless the driver was put into that path.
Why is that? Did it required now to be in relative path, or having "c:\...\...\????.sys" is wrong for ImagePath?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah,
this did the trick:

fileHandle = CreateFile("\.\"+driverName, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, IntPtr.Zero, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

Thanks to Tom :)

Now i'm getting a bluescreen but this is a driver-problem i have to work on. Driver is now correctly opened :)

Comment: The code above has lost the double slash in the argument 1. Add one \ to both slashes.